# Is it possible to access membership table via EF classes? To date I have been unsuccessful

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I am trying to do something that I thought would be simple.

Basically I am trying to create a EF POCO class from the existing "aspnet_Membership" table to add to my EF Data Model. I am actually using Devart's Entity Developer. I can import the table info to the designer and the model is updated with the table's information. However when I save the model the POCO is not generated. All my custom tables behave fine, but "aspnet_Membership" will not do anything. It is as if there is a secret flag on it saying "Do not generate POCO class" !!

Ultimately I am drying to achieve the following:

Organistion -< OrganisationUser >- aspnet_Membership

Any thoughts hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The ASP.NET membership system has a well-defined API - the Membership and Role Providers (and a few more). Why aren't you using that official, documented API?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Yes I could use the API, but I need to put in an StdOrgUser table to hold users for an organisation. I would have thought that I could also access these tables via EF. Afterall they are just tables?

Comment: If the poco is not generated, it sounds like it's a problem with Devarts software, not EF.  In any event, you don't need to do this.  You can simply get the userid of the current user using the membership API and add that to your where clause, as any join you would do can be done using the join keys you would otherwise use.

Comment: Ok, so for my understanding I should be able to create a POCO using MS's EF designer from the aspnet_Membershipt table? Also this is for admin purposes so, as an admin, I need to get hold of all UserIds to link the relevant ones to the appropriate organisation. It would be nice if I could access all the fields in aspnet_Membership using the usual LINQ strong typing/intellisense features.

Comment: Sorted. The POCOs were being generated, but were not being refreshed in VS2012 and then not included in the project. Now that I have sorted this I have been able to use LINQ as per normal with the membership tables. I only wanted to read from them to populate dropdowns etc. to populate my Organisation link table. Thanks all, hugely appreciated.